# exp system for python text RPG

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just learning python and I have been following a book for making a text RPG. I've made my way through the book and now I'm attempting to add experience and levelling starting with something really small. Right now I have enemies providing a random amount of experience using the random.randint() function and I can get that to display just fine, but I can't seem to get that to translate to the player class and then into the level up function.

```
def level_up(self):
    self.xp = self.xp + enemy.xp
    while self.xp >= self.lvlNext:
        self.lvl += 1
        self.xp = self.xp - self.lvlNext
        self.lvlNext = round(self.lvlNext * 1.5)
    print("Congatulations your level {}".format(self.lvl))
```

This is the function I'm attempting to use. It doesn't seem to be getting the input from enemy.xp 
I'm also new to stack overflow - if I can post the whole code file I will.

github link: https://github.com/GusRobins60/pythonTextRPG

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the signature you're currently using:

> ```
> def level_up(self):
> ```

You complain that

> It doesn't seem to be getting the input from enemy.xp.

You want to pass in `enemy` as a parameter:

```
 def level_up(self, enemy):
```

---

As an entirely separate matter, it is fine to say `self.xp = self.xp + enemy.xp`,
but it would be preferable to state it more concisely:

```
    self.xp += enemy.xp
```

and similarly for

```
    self.xp -= self.lvlNext
```

---

EDIT

Perhaps you'd care to derive `enemy` in this way:

```
    room = world.tile_at(self.x, self.y)
    enemy = room.enemy
```

It would be worth packaging that up as a helper function:

```
def get_enemy(x, y):
    room = world.tile_at(x, y)
    return room.enemy
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've edited the code as you've suggested including enemy in the def level_up(self, enemy). I'm looking for it to print the level up after it occurs. do you see where I am missing something. i will adjust the other code as you've suggested i just want to fix this issue first.